# Simultaneous embeddings of ring of integers into product of rings

Tags: nt.number-theory

This question is about something mentioned in Katz's "$p$-adic $L$-functions for CM fields" in section 2.0.

Let $K$ be a number field with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = d$ and ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\Sigma$ be the set of embeddings $\sigma \colon K \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and $K^{gal}$ the compositum of the fields $\sigma(K)$ over all $\sigma \in \Sigma$, the Galois closure of $K$. Then let $\mathcal{O}^{gal}$ be the ring of integers in $K^{gal}$, and $R$ an algebra over $\mathcal{O}^{gal}$. For each $\sigma \in \Sigma$, we have a ring homomorphism $\sigma \colon \mathcal{O}_K \otimes R \to R$ given on pure tensors by $n \otimes r \mapsto \sigma(n)r$. We can take them all together to produce

$$ \mathcal{O}_K \otimes R \to \prod_{\sigma \in \Sigma} R, \qquad n \otimes r \mapsto (\sigma(n)r)_\sigma. $$

Katz then states that this is an isomorphism if the discriminant of $K$ is invertible in $R$.

I'm trying to figure out what the image of this map is when the discriminant is not invertible. If $R$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$, it should be injective, just because each $\sigma$ is injective. I thought I had found an obstruction to surjectivity using the homomorphism of Abelian groups
$$ \prod_\sigma R \to R, \qquad T((r_\sigma)_\sigma) = \sum_\sigma r_\sigma $$
where the composition $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes R \to \prod_\sigma R \to R$ is $n \otimes r \mapsto \operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}(n)r$. The image is then the subgroup of $R$ generated by traces of elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$. However, the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by traces of elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not the different ideal as I had assumed (e.g. $Tr(1) = d$ is there regardless of whether any primes dividing $d$ ramify), and so it doesn't have as tight a connection to ramification in $K$ as I hoped.

Is there a nice description of the image of this map in general or in certain cases? I am most interested in the case when $R$ is the ring of integers in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: The matrix of this $R$-linear map is given by $(\sigma(e_i))_{\sigma,i}$ where $(e_i)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$. The square of the determinant of this matrix is the discriminant of $K$. If the discriminant is not a zero-divisor in $R$ then the map is injective (this is a general fact about linear maps between free modules of the same rank). Also, every surjective linear map between free modules of the same rank must be an isomorphism.

Comment: The case I'm working in ($R$ the ring of integers in a $p$-adic field) has $R$ a PID, which makes the theory of invariant factors useful. It won't give a perfect description, but it could at least give me an index.

Comment: Using SNF, the index of the image is $|R/\det f |$, where $f$ is your $R$-linear map, which is the square root of $|R/D_K| = |D_K|^{d/2}$, where $D_K$ is the discriminant of $K$. You can also factor the ideal $(D_K)$ over $R$, but maybe it doesn't give you all the information.

Comment: SNF meaning Smith Normal Form. Where does the exponent $d$ come in? Shouldn't $R/(\det f)R$ have size $\sqrt{|D_K|}$ if $(\det f)^2 = D_K$? (I'm abusing notation and writing $D_K$ for the size of $R/D_KR$.)

Comment: Sorry it should not be $|D_K|^{d/2}$ but $p^{v_p(D_K) n/2}$ where $n$ is the rank of $R$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, I think.

Comment: If we were working with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then $R/D_K$ has size $|D_K|$, but we are working over the ring of integers of a $p$-adic field.